# No AVD Installed

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android SDK on my Ubuntu 11.04. I have run a common `./android` to install. It was expected to see some options like "*Available packages*" to install android packages. But I haven't seen any options. After that have configured SDK Location path in Preferences in Eclipse I didn't get any SDK targets. When I open AVD Manager in Eclipse, it says "*no AVD available*". Could you please let me know how can I configure AVDs in my Eclipse?

Answer (score 7):

**To configure a basic Android Virtual Device (AVD)**

Open Eclipse and select `Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager`.
In the resulting window, select `Virtual Devices` in the left panel and click the `New` button on the right. This launches a new window to configure an AVD.In the first blank of this new window, give the device a name of your choice. Let's choose Simple2.2, indicating that this will be a relatively minimal device running Android 2.2.

Under the Target dropdown, select Android 2.2 - API Level 8.

Under SD Card enter 1024 for Size and be sure that the MiB dropdown is selected.

For Skin select Built-In and Default (HGVA).

Leave everything else as is and click Create AVD.

After a while (be patient, it may take a minute or so) this should create a new AVD with the characteristics specified that will appear in the list if Virtual Devices is selected in the left panel.

You might prefer a different configuration, but the one described above is considered optimal.

Comment: As for the missing SDK targets, the following should be helpful:

you have to open the SDK manager (type 'android' at the command prompt 
or open it in eclipse under the 'window' tab) go to settings, check 
the box for 'force https://...sources to be fetched', then go to 
available packages which should have the site 'https://dl- 
ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml' listed. If not, 
click 'add site' and put in this url. check this box and it will list sdk's and api's. Choose preferred ones and hit 'install selected' You should now have some targets 
available.

Comment: please let me know whether you have succeeded, so additional info can bee provided. Cheers!